# Data retrieval such that distribution is positive skewed

Tags: python, r, math, statistics

I have a pool of users called: u1, u2, u3 upto u1100

I wish to retrieve users from this pool such that resulting user distribution has a positive skew. 
(ie: a few users get retrieved many times and the vast majority of users get retrieved few times)
The desired shape should be as seen below.

[image: Histogram]

If I use a function as below where "user" is a list of users (u1, u2, u3 etc) the distribtion is normal: 
   myUser = random.choice(user)

I think providing a probability distribution to the random.choice() would work. Eg:
    myUser = random.choice(user, positiveSkewDistribution)

If this is the way to go, how do I get this positiveSkewDistribution file for the 1000 users ? I believe the file should have as many entries as the user file.

Comment: Can you provide some more info about the positiveSkewDistribution?

Comment: Your question is not clear. In Python, `random.choice()` does not use a normal distribution, but rather the uniform distribution. You also cannot use a second parameter, as in your attempted `random.choice(user, positiveSkewDistribution)`. Do you perhaps mean `random.choices()`? That also uses a uniform distribution by default. It can take a second parameter, but that is a sequence, not a file. Please clarify.